# How can I create a shared repo using "git clone"?

Tags: git, clone, init

The "git init" command has a parameter --shared which, from my reading, creates a repo with permission bits set to allow multiple people to access and update the repo.

I want to create the same type of repo but this time using "git clone". It too has a --shared parameter but from my reading does something totally different.

How can I clone a repo so that the cloned repo has the same permission bits as a "git init" with the --shared parameter ?

Comment: [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69672634/1256452)—which, rephrased, is "split `git clone` into its constituent steps so that you can pass `--shared` to the `git init` step—is the right one. It's worth mentioning that *wanting* this for a non-server-side clone is a clue that you're *probably* doing something inadvisable, though. Watch out for traps.

Comment: I'm looking at converting some old mainframe source management systems to GIT.  The idea of sharing source between users is very common. While I agree its not the Git way of doing things, because everyone gets their own copy.  Sharing a non-server-side clone is something they are used to, and just a small step towards "full Git implementation" (or should I say more regular Git implementation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the workaround of:

```
git init --shared aFolder
cd aFolder
git remote add origin /url/repo/to/clone
git fetch
git switch main
```

That way, you init first, then import the remote repository, instead of cloning it directly.